# Connecting to raspberry pi without sd card

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have my raspberry pi connected to my router with an ethernet cable. Can I connect to the raspberry pi with my laptop without having an sd card?

Comment: You may be able to get to the boot loader if it is configured for Enet. If not then you'll most likely need the card since that is where the kernel will be stored.

Comment: When you say "connect to the raspberry pi," what exactly do you mean? What do need to do with this connection?

Comment: basically want to run some python code on it